# Does Entity Framework support Oracle versioning

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

Oracle supports the concept of a version-ed entry into a table by use of the VID, DVC and DVS fields.

Are these concepts supported in E.F., could not find them in 5 but was hoping 6.x would sort this out.

Does anybody know if this is possible, and have a working example.

Comment: No I don't think so. I guess you'll have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Oracle guy, but...

Optimistic concurrency in EF is implemented via concurrency tokens.
Concurrency token is just a field, which satisfies for two conditions:

1) its value is server-generated (for example, `rowversion` in MS SQL, or field, populated from sequences in any RDBMS, which supports sequences);
2) it is mapped to a property, which is configured with [`IsConcurrencyToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679501%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method in fluent API (or corresponding attribute with data annonations).

The thing, which makes concurrency token different from calculated field/property, is that EF LINQ provider generates additional `WHERE` clause, when updating database entries.

So, I can't see anything, that prevents from using optimistic concurrency tokens with Oracle, Firebird, MySQL etc. It's not a MSSQL feature only.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I'll have a look into this.